# Trying to set up a data source in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to create a data source for my local sql server using the server name `(local)`.  But I keep getting the following error

```
Connection verification failed for data source: sqlserver
java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket. Unknown host: (local)
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver]Error establishing socket. Unknown host: (local)
```

On the reporting services I'm using `(local)` as the server name and it is working fine,

Ted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled external TCP connections on your sql server?

Try using `localhost` instead of `local`. (or add `127.0.0.1 local` to your hosts file)

Comment: This shows you how to enable TCP connections, with screenshots! http://www.mattgifford.co.uk/local-sql-server-2008-coldfusion-datasource

Comment: Actually I think he is using the special keyword `(local)`,  parenthesis included, which may not work with jdbc. But your suggestion of using ip `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` should do it.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use (local) this is a Microsoft ONLY term and won't be understood by anything external.

You need to specify the servername as the name of the server.

If the SQL Server is the same server as ColdFusion you can then use localhost

If not use the DNS or local IP name of the sever, ie sql.local or 192.168.1.22

If the server is external to your You will need TCP/IP configured and port 1433 open also. But by default this should be setup, you may just need to open your firewall to allow access through port 1433.

In a network environment, you would normally use local IP to get LAN access to your DB, but if  database is really external you need a real IP / domain